# Using relative path for Fetch network call, getting "unrecognized url"

Tags: react-native, fetch, reactjs-native

Everything I read says that you can pass a relative url into a fetch call eg

`fetch('/path/to/resource/')`

but when I do that, I get an "unrecognized url" error. Instead I'm being forced to do an absolute url for my local host, which makes it a pain for my team to use my code eg

`fetch('http://123.0.0.44:8000/path/to/resource')`

I'm only working in Android currently. Do I need to add the base url to the project or something? Or do I have to fashion a dynamic absolute path by pulling in the base url from somewhere? I'd rather just use the relative path, if that's possible, but I can't find anyone else having the same trouble as I am using it. Seems to "just work" for everyone else.

Comment: Are those examples React Native apps?

Comment: Yes this is from a React Native project

Comment: Could you show me any of those? Maybe there is some trick we haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2):

The possible solution is to create a configuration file, that would have f.e. 'SERVER_HOST' variable, that would include 'http://123.0.0.44:8000'. So, after you import the config file you could write something like

```
fetch( config.SERVER_HOST + '/path/to/resource' )
```

Comment: That's my localhost ip though. If my other team members were to pull my code, it wouldn't be correctly pointing to their localhost.

I'm sure I could look up how to get the server to template its ip onto my files so that I can always have the proper base URL, but I'm mostly curious as to if others are seeing this behavior with fetch in React Native, or if my situation is unique for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As said on fecebook's official react-native website you should enter URL as ebdpoint. [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this when making a project that shares code between React Native `v0.59.5` and React Native Web `v0.11.2`. `fetch` is a global API available in both environments (but admittedly may need polyfilling for the latter if you're targeting very old browsers). Interestingly, React Native's implementation of fetch [is identical](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/fetch.js#L16) to the kind that you'd polyfill for web browsers (`whatwg-fetch`), so their underlying [XmlHttpRequest](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js) implementation is probably where things differ.

```js
fetch("some/relative/resource.txt")
.then((response) => { console.log("Responded!"); })
.catch(console.error);

// On React Native, logs the error "Network request failed".
// On React Native Web, logs "Responded!"
```

As I was connecting to localhost over the `http://` protocol, I double-checked that my App Transport security was set up correctly (it was).

In the case of React Native, no corresponding request is even shown in the network debugger, so I suspected a security violation. Then I realised that it's quite obvious: on React Native Web, the app is always hosted on the web, so it's natural that `fetch()` requests are made relative to that domain. But React Native apps are not hosted on a domain.

It looks like React Native's implementation [passes the URL onto RCTNetworking.sendRequest()](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js#L518), and then ultimately on to `RCTNetworking.mm` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking.mm#L272), at least for iOS. It ends up as a `[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]` using an NSURL formed from the dictionary via `[RCTConvert NSURL:query[@"url"]]`. The implementation of RCTConvert [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTConvert.m#L100) shows that the NSURL is initialised using the `[NSURL URLWithString:path]` method with no `relativeToURL` path, so the URL is relative to nothing (and may well return `nil`)! So it's no wonder that it fails. It's also clear from the implementation that there's no way in React Native to globally declare a URL base to base such URLs relative to.

There's definitely potential for a Pull Request in here to improve parity between React Native and React Native Web. But until then, something along the lines of phillipsh's solution, wherein you explicitly detail the host domain, will have to do..!

## Relevant reading

- React Native docs: [Networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)